# Xamarin Forms (iOS): This application is modifying the autolayout engine

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Since I added translations between two ContentViews (to go from one to the other one nicely), I have the following logs:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

```
Stack:(
0   Foundation                          0x0000000110da2ec6 _AssertAutolayoutOnAllowedThreadsOnly + 77
1   Foundation                          0x0000000110da2b89 -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding] + 61
2   Foundation                          0x0000000110bb1ebb -[NSISEngine optimize] + 108
3   Foundation                          0x0000000110da00ac -[NSISEngine performPendingChangeNotifications] + 84
4   UIKit                               0x00000001116f89f9 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2211
5   QuartzCore                          0x00000001138a63ee -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
6   QuartzCore                          0x00000001138aa4dd _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
7   QuartzCore                          0x0000000113832ded _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 365
8   QuartzCore                          0x000000011385e704 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
9   MyProject.iOS                         0x000000010f6bbd39 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
10  ???                                 0x000000012f8e9462 0x0 + 5092840546
11  ???                                 0x000000013025827c 0x0 + 5102731900
12  MyProject.iOS                       0x000000010f5272c9 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1273
13  MyProject.iOS                       0x000000010f5dbaa8 do_runtime_invoke + 88
14  MyProject.iOS                       0x000000010f61bf9e start_wrapper + 718
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000117fe06c1 _pthread_body + 340
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000117fe056d _pthread_body + 0
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000117fdfc5d thread_start + 13
)
```

This is my code:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
{
    DetailContentView.Children.Insert(0, masterDetailContentView);
    await DetailContentView.Children[1].TranslateTo(App.ScreenWidth - 100, 0, 250);
    await DetailContentView.Children[1].TranslateTo(App.ScreenWidth, 0, 50);
    DetailContentView.Children.RemoveAt(1);
});
```

where DetailContentView is a Grid, masterDetailContentView is the ContentView that will appear and DetailContentView.Children[1] is the ContentView that will disappear.

This piece of code works but I want to remove the logs.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you invoke the code above ?

Comment: In a MasterDetailPage, in an async method called UpdateDetailContentView, that change the Content of MasterDetailPage.Detail.